# Update same text in ten documents easy?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am using Microsoft Word in 2016. I have ten documents with same header, text in the beginning and text in the end. The text in the middle of the dokument is custom for each document. I do not want to update all ten documents if I for e.g update the text in the beginning. But the other documents should not be affected if I update the custom text. How do I do this in the smartest way? I can create all ten documents again if there is an easier way of update them later the way I want.

Example of a dokument

> Same Header on all dokuments
>
> This text is same on all documents. This text is same on all
>   documents. This text is same on all documents.
>
> This is a custom text for this document. This is a custom text for
>   this document. This is a custom text for this document. This is a
>   custom text for this document.
>
> This text is same on all documents. This text is same on all
>   documents. This text is same on all documents.

Comment: depending on the formatting / length / complexity of the custom text you can use mail merge, store custom texts in Excel, store same parts in a Word template and merge them whenever you need. (there is no easy way maintaining parts of documents to be identical just as you've described).

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the shared parts into separate documents and than insert them into the ten documents as linked objects.

Here are the steps for a shared header, you can do the same with the footer or any other shared parts:

1. Create a header document with the content you want to appear on every document.
2. Open one of the ten documents.
3. On the `Insert` tab click `Object`.
4. In the `Object` dialog box switch to the `Create from File` tab.
5. Using the `Browse...` button find  the header document you created in step 1.
6. Check the `Link to file` checkbox and click `OK`. See screenshot below.
7. Save the file.
8. Repeat steps 2-7 for the other nine documents.

[image]

Now you have a shared header. Try modifying the header and see the changes reflected in all ten documents. You can do the same with the footer and other common parts.

When opening those ten files you may be prompted to update content from the linked file(s), that's normal and you can click Yes.

Also note that if you email the document to someone else or store it where there is no longer a way to reach the linked document, the file will show the last state of the linked document but naturally it will not be able to update it.